# what should application.scss look like when using bootstrap-sass ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

when using [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) the documentation says to:

> remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from
>   the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

my current application.scss looks like

```
 /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *

 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "*";
```

the problem is if I want to override bootstrap styles i have to use !important and i cant access bootstrap mixins and variables

so what should application.scss look like when using bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. About require**

`*= require_self` means use this file (application.scss)

`*= require_tree .` means use all file on folder(tree) `stylesheets`

In my opinion, you should and use require all file on tree instead `require_tree`. Since with require file by file, you can control the order of which file you want to run.

So keep `*= require_self` and remove `*= require_tree .` and require all file you need.

My example application.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require nprogress
 *= require nprogress-bootstrap
 *= require nprogress-turbolinks5
 *= require global    
 *= require articles
 *= require search
 *= require footer
 *= require header
 *= require contacts
 *= require notices
 *= require aui-flash
 *= require_self
 */


@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**2. Override bootstrap styles**

To override bootstrap styles, follow this [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Another way to change style bootstrap is, put an ID to parent of item or its self which you want to change

Ex:

You have `<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>`

Now you want to change class `btn-primary` to `background-color: red`

You can try `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="red-primary">Hello</button>`

And your style:

```
#red-primary.btn-primary{
  background-color: red;
}
```

But with this way, every you want to override style, the item must be has a ID. May be not good.

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to use `sass`. In you application.sass

```
@import nprogress
@import global
@import articles
```

Comment: What about the documentation for bootstrap-sass it explicitly says not to use *=require statements in application.scss if you want access to bootstrap mixins and variables

Comment: From you question `my current application.scss looks like`, I see you are using `scss`. But if you want to use `sass`, the answer in your question. `Instead, use @import to import Sass files.` Just replace `*=require` to `@import`. I update my answer